# plesk api shell access

Tags: api, ssh, plesk

I am trying to create a script to add new domain names in Plesk, using Plesk API.

My script:

```
<packet version='1.4.2'> 
<domain>
<add>
   <gen_setup>
      <name>domain.com</name>
      <client_id>1</client_id>
      <ip_address>127.0.0.1</ip_address>
      <status>0</status>
   </gen_setup>
   <hosting>
      <vrt_hst>
          <ftp_login>username</ftp_login>
          <ftp_password>password</ftp_password>
          <php>true</php>
          <ssi>true</ssi>
          <cgi>true</cgi>
          <php_safe_mode>false</php_safe_mode>
          <ip_address>127.0.0.1</ip_address>
      </vrt_hst>
   </hosting>
</add>
</domain>
</packet>
```

The script adds a new domain, but the ssh access is not working. I  need help with adding the shell access to this script. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on plesk/protocol version. Try to add `<shell>/bin/bash</shell>` in `<vrt_hst>...</vrt_hst>`

Next query works for Plesk 10/11:

```
<packet version="1.6.3.0">
<webspace>
<add>
   <gen_setup>
      <name>example.com</name>
      <owner-id>1</owner-id>
      <htype>vrt_hst</htype>
      <ip_address>10.0.0.1</ip_address>
      <status>0</status>
   </gen_setup>
   <hosting>
      <vrt_hst>
          <property>
            <name>shell</name>
            <value>/bin/bash</value>
          </property>
          <property>
            <name>ftp_login</name>
            <value>ftp16se4fdf0</value>
          </property>
          <property>
            <name>ftp_password</name>
            <value>qweqwe</value>
          </property>
          <ip_address>10.0.0.1</ip_address>
       </vrt_hst>
    </hosting>
</add>
</webspace>
</packet>
```