# Plesk 12 Subscription "shell" via XML API

Tags: xml, plesk

Is it possible to set the subscription shell option of an subscription via xml api?

I can't read anything about it.

I see it is possible via cmd "/usr/local/psa/bin/subscription -u {subscription} -shell /usr/local/psa/bin/chrootsh"

But how is it possible via xml api?

Kindly regards

Comment: pssible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855710/plesk-api-shell-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer to define shell at creating domain: [plesk api shell access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855710/plesk-api-shell-access)

Try this query to set shell for existed domain/subscription:

```
<packet>
<webspace>
<set>
   <filter>
      <name>example.com</name>
   </filter>
   <values>
    <hosting>
      <vrt_hst>
          <property>
            <name>shell</name>
            <value>/bin/bash</value>
          </property>
       </vrt_hst>
      </hosting>
    </values>
</set>
</webspace>
</packet>
```

Comment: additional i had to add the **<ip_address>{ip_of_hosting}</ip_address>** node into the <vrt_hst> node for plesk 12 xml api. works great, thanks